# Magento2 apply coupon code button at checkout payment step after refresh

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento2 EE 2.1.3.

In it when i apply the coupon code at checkout page at payment step it works perfect and button text change from 'Apply Discount' to 'Cancel Coupon'. But when i refresh the page button again change to 'Apply Discount'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether it was a Magento2 EE 2.1.3 issue or custom theme issue. So first, I copy the related js file vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/discount.js into custom theme at related location, and then in it I have change at line number 18

from

```
couponCode = ko.observable(null)
```

to

```
couponCode = ko.observable(totals()['coupon_code'])
```